# Rails and DataTable how to pass the JSON Document

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datatable

Sorry for the bad title.  I am new to Rails and Javascript.  I setup a DataTable using child rows following the DataTables documentation using a single ajax call to a JSON file.

I got that all working I now want to use my Rails controller to get the JSON from a Mongo DB.  I also have that part working. What I am confused about is probably very simple and I am used to building a Rails table with active record BUT here I had a separate javascript called tests.js with my DataTable definition and the ajax call to a file.  Can I now just pass in the JSON from the View somehow? I am not sure how to switch from the ajax call to using the JSON I now have from my controller

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#queryone_table').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "transactionType" },
        { "data": "collationId" },
        { "data": "licensePlate" },
        { "data": "description" },
        { "data": "startDate" },
        { "data": "FeedComplete" },
        { "data": "RepoComplete" },
        { "data": "feedProcessingDuration" },
        { "data": "completeDuration" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );
```

Objects.txt I would now like to be a var from my View?  With active record and MySQL I would build the table in the view looping over a dataset from controller but with the child row code already done in javascript I would like to leave that.

full javascript code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#queryone_table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "/objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "transactionType" },
            { "data": "collationId" },
            { "data": "licensePlate" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "startDate" },
            { "data": "FeedComplete" },
            { "data": "RepoComplete" },
            { "data": "feedProcessingDuration" },
            { "data": "completeDuration" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );


    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#queryone_table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();

            tr.addClass('shown');

        }
    } );

 } );


function format ( d ) {
    var foo = '<table id="queryinner_table" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" border="1" style="padding-left:50px;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed dataTable no-footer sub-table">';
    // loop over table rows
    var trow = "";
    for (var i=0; i< d.nextrow.length; i++) {

      var foo2 = '<tr>'+
                    '<td>Transaction Step:</td>'+
                    '<td>'+d.nextrow[i].transactionStep+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+d.nextrow[i].elapsedSeconds+'</td>'+
                  '</tr>'
      trow = trow + foo2

    } //for loop

    var foo2 = '</table>';
    var res = foo.concat(trow);
    res = res.concat(foo2);

    return res;
  }
```

Comment: I do not understand very well. You need to pass data from database to datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was poorly worded I have started a new project and will ask a few questions based on that code rather than rewrite this one.